# Boot strap checks fails elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Using Elasticsearch sink connector to insert data to ES 7.2 instance hosted on VM. 
Getting this :  `Elastic search max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]`

Is it possible to ignore bootstrap checks ?
How can I increase the virtual memory for Elasticsearch in the docker container ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap checks inspect a variety of Elasticsearch and system settings. If youre in development mode, any bootstrap checks that fail appear as warnings in the Elasticsearch log. If youre in production mode failed bootstrap will cause Elasticsearch to refuse to start.

Elasticsearch work mode is configured implicit. As soon as you configure a network setting like `network.host`,Elasticsearch assumes that you are moving to production and will upgrade the above warnings to exceptions.

Regarding your specific case you need to increase it on the host machine  not the docker by running this command:
`sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` . and then restart your docker-containers.

BTW not recommended but if you are running a single node you can skip the bootstrap checks by not binding transport to an external interface or by binding transport to an external interface and setting the discovery type to single-node.